# How to get markers after calling drive directions in Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, driving-directions

I just started working using Google Maps API yesterday, and trying to set up drive directions to my map. My problem is: when I call the function load,

```
// [...]  
gdir = new GDirections(map, directionsPanel);  
// [...]  
gdir.load("from: " + fromAddress + " to: " + toAddress);
```

it returns a map whose markers are not draggable. So, I need to make them draggable in order to recalculate the directions, but I can't get the markers objects.

Someone knows how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a handler on the *GDirections* object for the *addoverlay* event:

```
GEvent.addListener(gdir, "addoverlay", onGDirectionsAddOverlay);
```

When your *onGDirectionsAddOverlay* handler is called you can iterate through the new markers and replace them with draggable copies:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= gdir.getNumRoutes(); i++) 
{
    var originalMarker = gdir.getMarker(i);
    latLngs[i] = originalMarker.getLatLng();
    icons[i] = originalMarker.getIcon();
    newMarkers[i] = new GMarker(latLngs[i], { icon: icons[i], draggable: true, title: 'Kan flyttes' });
    map.addOverlay(newMarkers[i]);

    // add stuff to your newMarkers[i] drag end event...
    // ...

    //Bind 'click' event to original markers 'click' event
    copyClick(newMarkers[i], originalMarker);

    // Now we can remove the original marker safely
    map.removeOverlay(originalMarker);
}
```

You can find a working example of this [here](http://www.cannonade.net/geo.php?test=geo1) ([source](http://www.cannonade.net/geo1.js)).